# firebase not correctly initialized: Googleservice-Info.plist not located on MacOS using VScode

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using macOS Big Sur, Visual Studio Code with the current stable Flutter release.

1. I've done :

```
flutter clean, rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock; 
flutter pub get; pod init; pod update; 
pod install; turned it off and back on; 
pulled it out and blew on it then stuck it back in
```

2. My Podfile is updated for current ios and I've copied the 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file to just about every directory including Runner/ lib/ main, Flutter/ etc.
3. I've restarted my mac and vs code several times, checked pubspec.yaml for accuracy, rerun the autogenerated files from the freeze.
4. This error occurs when compiling for ios using Visual Studio and the iPhone 12 simulator from Xcode.
5. No error occurs and the program compiles/works as expected when compiling for android using Visual Studio and the Pixel 3 Emulator from Android Studio.
6. I have not tried this compile on XCode - I prefer using VSCode on Mac and would like to stay in one development program environment for all platforms (visual studio code)
7. The error I am receiving at compile time is:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
package:notes2/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           62.0s
7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:51910/4RdXrGyMG2A=/ws
7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to the project?
View the iOS Installation documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:88
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Firebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:41
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main
package:notes2/main.dart:13
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I have thoroughly gone through the iOS Installation documentation and it says nothing about where to put this file or any environmental variable settings for the Visual Studio code development environment.

Anyone's input that has experience in getting this working with VSCode would be appreciated. I'm sure it works fine in XCode on mac.

My Podfile

```
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

My pubspec.yaml file

```
name: notes2
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  another_flushbar: 1.10.17
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.2
  dfunc: 0.6.2
  firebase_auth: 1.0.1
  firebase_core: 1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: 7.0.0
  freezed_annotation: 0.14.1
  get_it: 6.0.0
  google_sign_in: 5.0.1
  injectable: 1.2.2
  oxidized: 4.1.0
  uuid: 3.0.2
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: 1.12.2
  freezed: 0.14.1+1
  injectable_generator: 1.2.2
  lint: 1.5.3

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
      - GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Comment: I recommend you get comfortable with Xcode as it brings benefits in the future: modifying `.plist` files (though you can also use ProperTree), other hidden configuration files which Xcode exposes in its IDE. I had the same idea when first learning React Native, I wanted to stay inside the VS Code and was afraid to try Xcode. Specifically in this instance, you might discover it also doesn't work on Xcode, and might find other useful error messages.

Comment: Thanks. Visual studio code is a good system. I have been looking at InteilliJ as well, but for now will stick with VSCode. Worst case, I will just compile for android as this is a project more for my personal experience than anything else. But I would like to know the solution to this problem on VSCode though.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you add the 'GoogleService-Info.plist' from VS code but you must add this file using Xcode

to do that:

- Open file /$project_name/ios/Runner.xcworkspace using Xcode
- Right click on Runner folder
- Click add files to Runner.
- Chose the 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file and click Add.

[Xcode screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwRdg.png)
[image: Xcode screen shoot 2]

Comment: I've seen that comment on another thread. What do you mean: "Add this file using Xcode" . I haven't seen any type of injection xcode command to import this file or variable. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: Xcode manages files for you. Just because its in the directory doesn't mean Xcode knows about it. You might hundreds of files in your project, but none in your Xcode if you haven't added them. Add them by dragging the file into the `Project navigator → Runner`. Having said that, I'm not sure if this file needs to be added to Xcode for it to work.

Comment: can you please check my answer after edite

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I'm looking for the Visual Studio code way in this question though.

Comment: Actually Amin. Your solution works for my Visual Studio code problem!

Comment: Yes, it will work you just nee to add this one time from Xcode and this will effect on your VS Code :)

Comment: Solution: I loaded Xcode, and followed Amin's steps with the Google plist file I downloaded from Firebase dashboard. After adding the file to the Xcode program as Amin's screenshot shows, I went back to the Visual Studio code editor and ran the debugger. It connected and the only error it shows now after Xcode build done is: No app has been configured yet. The application loads as expected on: Visual Studio Code using Iphone 12 Simulator from Xcode. Thanks Amin!

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the [Flutterfire guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios). Since the guide shows you how to do it in Xcode because it needs to be done via Xcode, you should use that instead of VS code. **You cannot do it through VS code.** You can still code the rest of your project in VS code.

> Next you must add the file to the project using Xcode (adding manually via the filesystem won't link the file to the project). Using Xcode, open the project's ios/{projectName}.xcworkspace file. Right click Runner from the left-hand side project navigation within Xcode and select "Add files", as seen below:

Comment: Amin's answer above got it running on Visual Studio code

Comment: I think I've diagnosed your misunderstanding. A lot of configuration for iOS needs to be done on Xcode. You can still code your flutter app in VS code, but you can't ignore Xcode for configuration.

Comment: You are correct Ben. Thanks for the responses. You can code in VS code, but you cannot ignore the Xcode environmental(?) settings.